# Android Studio CPU Profiler - start recording an app launch

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling, android-studio-3.0, android-profiler

I want to get a method trace while cold starting my app.

According to [`CPU Profiler` docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler.html#method_traces), I need to click on the `Record` button on the `CPU Profiler` to start a method trace recording, however I want this recording on the app from the instant the new app process start.

I've tried running my app using the 'profile' toolbar button instead of the 'run' button, but that doesn't seem to do anything, and I don't get the recording started.

I can still use the old method trace using `Debug.startMethodTracing()`/`Debug.stopMethodTracing()` but that generates trace files compatible with the old interface in Studio, how do I do the same with the new interface?